# Flutter display blank screen when tap on button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

the flutter code below executes a view, when I click on the **FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.calendar)** to show the calendar selection, I get the completely blank screen what is this due to?

**Flutter Code:**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:custom_date_range_picker/custom_date_range_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:nice_button/nice_button.dart';
import 'package:quote/Model/Ferie.dart';
import 'package:quote/Model/Supporto.dart';
import 'package:quote/Model/Utente.dart';
import 'package:quote/View/Home.dart';
import 'package:quote/utils/support.dart';
import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';

import '../Barcode/BarcodeManager.dart';
import 'dialog/CustomDialog.dart';

bool isShowingMainData = true;
var status = false;
String base64File = null;
var urlprofiloImage;

class FerieScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FerieScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _FerieScreenState();
  }
}

class _FerieScreenState extends State<FerieScreen> {
  DateTime startData, endData;
  List<Ferie> listaFerie;
  var check = false;

  Future<bool> loadData() async {
    listaFerie = await Ferie.ricerca();
    urlprofiloImage = await Utente.getProfiloImmagine();
    return true;
  }

  inserisci(BuildContext context) {
    if (startData != null && endData != null) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return CustomDialogBox(
              title: "Invio Richiesta Ferie",
              descriptions:
                  "Data Inizio: " + Verifica.castDate(startData) + "\nData Fine: " + Verifica.castDate(endData),
              text: "Invia Richiesta",
              dataFine: endData,
              dataInzio: startData,
            );
          });
    } else {
      log("Date non compilate");
      alert(context, "Attenzione", "Le date devono essere selezionate", AlertType.error);
    }
  }

  ///Funzione che mostra una data a video
  Future<void> selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    showCustomDateRangePicker(context, dismissible: true, minimumDate: DateTime.now(), endDate: DateTime.now(),
        onApplyClick: (start, end) {
      startData = start;
      endData = end;
    }, onCancelClick: () {}, maximumDate: null);
  }

  Widget getFerieWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return listaFerie != null
        ? Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: listaFerie.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final item = listaFerie[index];
              return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                title: Text("Stato Richiesta Ferie: " + item.Stato.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                        color: item.Stato == "INATTESA"
                            ? Colors.orange
                            : item.Stato == "APPROVATA"
                                ? Colors.green
                                : Colors.red)),
                subtitle: Text(
                    "Data Inizio: " +
                        item.DataInizio.toString() +
                        "\nData Fine: " +
                        item.DataFine.toString() +
                        "\nMotivazione: " +
                        item.Motivazione,
                    style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              ));
            },
          ))
        : Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
            child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
              value: 0.8,
            ),
          );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: loadData(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return new Text("Not data load");
          } else {
            return Scaffold(
              resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
              body: Column(children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    const Expanded(
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text('Richiesta Ferie'),
                        subtitle: Text("Clicca qui sul button del calendario"),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.calendar),
                        onPressed: () {
                          selectDate(context);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                new NiceButton(
                  radius: 30,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  text: "Richiesta Ferie",
                  icon: Icons.local_airport,
                  gradientColors: [secondColor, firstColor],
                  onPressed: () {
                    inserisci(context);
                  },
                  background: null,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                        child: Expanded(
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.backward),
                            onPressed: () {
                              const gp = const HomeViewScreen();
                              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => gp));
                            },
                          ),
                        ))
                  ],
                ),
                getFerieWidget(context),
              ]),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the `selectDate(context)` inside the `onPressed` being executed despite the blank screen?

Comment: Hello riki, any reason for use a return type Future<void> and an async function? By documentation it seems showCustomDateRangePicker is not an async.

Comment: i tried to remove async but the result doesn't change @barracus

Comment: @Dani3le_ yes...

Comment: I know it's not an answer but, if it doesn't complicate the things too much, consider to use a most-liked packages like https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker

Comment: @barracus i need to use this library custom_date_range_picker